# How to check mysql table with python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I want to create a license system for my code in Python.

Now I am facing an issue: how can I check if an integer is contained in my MySQL database?

Here are some variables for the database.

```
'License' Database: license|user
Database name = License
columns = license and user
```

Here is my code I got so far:

````
def check_data():
    license = str(11585728)
    val = f'"18742974","USER"'
    sql = "SELECT * FROM License WHERE license = ''11585728''"

    cursor.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
    cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")```
````

Comment: Try with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM License WHERE license = ''11585728''` and check if the returned number is 0 or higher. In the former case you'll know there's no instance of that number, in the latter you'll acknowledge the opposite.

Comment: Now it returns me this errror:
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM License WHERE license = 18742974' at
line 1

Comment: Try with `sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM License WHERE license = '11585728';"`.

Comment: Yeah okay there is no more error but now it returns me 'none'.

Comment: have you checked whether that license is in the db or not by hand?

Comment: I checked multiply times